# How can I find similar files within two directories in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, file, directory, compare

I have an assignment that follows:

> Loop through every file in ~files, check if the same file exists in
> ~oUser/files, if it does then move the file in oUser to .bkp.
> Once you've ensured the file does not exist copy the file from your
> home directory to oUser's home directory.

I have a hard time understanding the question but I started breaking it down one step at a time and I can not get past understanding how to find common files.

This is what I have done so far:

```
cd files
touch t1.txt
touch t2.txt
touch t3.txt

cd ~oUser/files
touch t2.txt
touch t4.txt
```

So I learned loop to be as:

```
for FILE in ~/files; do echo $FILE; done
for FILE in ~/oUser/files; do echo $FILE; done
```

I thought I can output the names into a specific file and then use grep for commonalities

```
find ~/files -type f > files.txt

find ~oUser/files -type f > oUserfiles.txt

grep -l files.txt oUserfiles.txt > file.txt
```

but when I open the `file.txt` it's empty.

Comment: You can use `[ -e "~oUser/files/$FILE" ]` to check if the file exists. Your `find` isn't working because `find` includes the path.

Comment: @lawruble13: Quotes prevent `bash` from expanding `~` or `~oUser`.

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks, you're correct. [ -e ~oUser/files/"$FILE" ] should work.

Comment: Define "same file". Same filename, or same contents, or both?

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting this. The O.P. has actually spent time trying to solve the problem and set up a reasonable testing set. ++ from me. I'll comment that you can `touch` multiple files in one go, i.e. `touch file1.txt file2.txt ....` . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to write your assignment for you, but here is some information you may find useful.

**Find**

`find` prints files that it finds prefaced by the path you give it. So, if you had the file `example.txt` in `~/files/`, this would be printed by `find ~/files -type f` as `$HOME/files/example.txt`. This means that if you run `find` in different folders, the outputs won't match, so even if `grep` worked the way you interpreted (i.e. matching lines in files), it still wouldn't work because the paths are different.

**Grep**

`grep` expects input in the form

```
grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]
grep [OPTIONS] [-e PATTERN | -f FILE] [FILE...]
```

as detailed in its [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep). The `-l` flag changes `grep`s behaviour to just printing the names of files which match, so `grep -l files.txt oUserfiles.txt` just checks if any line in `oUserfiles.txt` matches the literal string `files.txt`, and if it does then it outputs the literal string `oUserfiles.txt`. I recommend reading that man page, but I will note that the `-f` flag pulls patterns line by line from the first file, if you still want to do that.`

**Checking file existence**

You can check if a particular file exists using `[ -e path/to/file.txt ]`. The spaces there are important, so don't omit those. In order to check in ~, and using a variable, you'll need something along the lines of `[ -e ~/files/"$FILE" ]`, which allows bash to expand the `~` to `$HOME` (Thanks to @Cyrus!).

Comment: @DenisaFagi :  All good stuff here. Also look a the `comm` utility and think about how to redirect `ls` listings into separate files so you can then use `comm`. (note the use of `-1`, `-2` and `-3` options). There will still be more to do after that to move the files. Good luck.